# Difference between SelectItem[] manufacturerOptions and List<SelectItem> manufacturerOptions

Tags: jsf, primefaces

May be a stupid question,If I use `List<SelectItem>` instead of `SelectItem[]`, the datatable filtering showcase doesn't work at all in primefaces datatable filtering [example](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/datatableFiltering.jsf)

In the Showcase TableBean.java, This works

```
private SelectItem[] manufacturerOptions;
manufacturerOptions = createFilterOptions(manufacturers);
```

But If I use

```
List<SelectItem> manufacturerOptions:
manufacturerOptions = createFilterOptions(manufacturers);
```

Filter doesn;t work

**XHTML**

```
<p:column id="manufacturerColumn" filterBy="#{car.manufacturer}"   
                headerText="Manufacturer" footerText="exact"  
                filterOptions="#{tableBean.manufacturerOptions}"  
                filterMatchMode="exact">  
            <h:outputText value="#{car.manufacturer}" />  
        </p:column>
```

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like `<p:column>` only supports arrays and no lists. So it is either simply not supported or a bug. You should report this to the PrimeFaces team.